# How to write a ProgrammableSource filter to display a numpy array as a vtkImageData in ParaView?

Tags: python, paraview

So instead of storing every data we have in yet another format to make it displayable by ParaView, I wanted to use the python interface ParaView offers to directly load our data from our current file format and display it.

To test this out I wanted to create a simple `ProgrammableSource` filter that outputs a vtkImageData and fill it with some data.

I encountered three issues:

- First, the data is not displayed (not even as an outline representation)
- I could not find a way to set the values without looping
- I did not find a good online source that could help me

Here is what I have so far. No complaints from ParaView, but also nothing is rendered.

```python
import numpy as np
import vtk
import vtk.util.numpy_support as ns

img = self.GetImageDataOutput()
img.SetDimensions(3,4,5)
img.AllocateScalars(vtk.VTK_DOUBLE, 1)


dims = img.GetDimensions()
img.SetOrigin(0,0,0)
img.SetSpacing(0.55, 0.55, 0.55)

for z in range(dims[2]):
  for y in range(dims[1]):
    for x in range(dims[0]):
      img.SetScalarComponentFromDouble(x,y,z,0, 1.0*x*y*z)
```

**NOTE:** If it is easier to use the python shell of ParaView directly instead of the ProgrammableSource, this would also be ok.

Answer (score 4):

For defining `vtkImageData` output with the Programmable Source, one also has to take care of setting some information in the `RequestInformation` phase of the pipeline execution. Insert the following into the `Script (RequestInformation)` property:

```
from paraview import util

op = self.GetOutput()
util.SetOutputWholeExtent(self, [0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4])
```

This information was adapted from information available at http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter.

Comment: Wow, this already looks promising. However, is it possible to have the numpy values interpreted as element values and not as node values, as in the first entry is the value for the first voxel, not the first wireframe node?

Comment: In VTK and ParaView image data, point data represents voxel values, and the voxel centers are the "points" that have the associated data. It's a little confusing, I realize, but everything in VTK that deals with image data is written with that assumption.